# MYSQL search query use of descending order limit 1 and use left

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

example i have a table like this

```
ID    CODE        NAME
'1', '201600001', 'abc'
'2', '201600002', 'bcd'
'3', '201700003', 'def'
```

then i want to get the code by descending order (Select id, code, name from table_sample order by code desc limit 1;) but in selecting the code i only want the first 4 characters, because code is a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uh, is this what you want?

```
select a.id, left(s.code, 4) as code, s.name
from table_sample s
order by s.code desc
limit 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

This was my stab at it;

```
SELECT ID, SUBSTRING(CODE, 0, 4), NAME FROM tbl_sample ORDER BY CODE DESC LIMIT 1
```

Is that any good?